# Java "Quicksave" Execution

Tags: java, performance

The problem I seem to have hit is one relating to loading times; I'm not running on a particularly *fast* machine by any means, but I still want to dabble into neural networks. In short, I have to load 336,600,000 integers into one large array (I'm using the MNIST database; each image is 28x28, which amounts to 748  pixels per image, times 45,000 images). It works fine, and surprisingly I don't run out of RAM, but... it takes 4 and a half hours, just to get the data into an array.
I can supply the rest of the code if you want me to, but here's the function that runs through the file.

```
public static short[][] readfile(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
short[][] array = new short[10000][784];
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/MNIST/" + fileName + ".csv"));
br.readLine();
try {
  for (short i = 1; i < 45000; i++) {
    String line = br.readLine();
    for (short j = 0; j < 784; j++) {
      array[i][j] = Short.parseShort(line.split(",")[j]);
    }
  }
  br.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
return array;
```

}

What I want to know is, is there some way to "quicksave" the execution of the program so that I don't have to rebuild the array for every small tweak?

Note: I haven't touched Java in a while, and my code is mostly chunked together from a lot of different sources. I wouldn't be surprised if there were some serious errors (or just Java "no-nos"), it would actually help me a *lot* if you could fix them if you answer.

Edit: Bad question, I'm just blind... sorry for wasting time

Edit 2: I've decided after a while that instead of loading all of the images, and then training with them one by one, I could simply train one by one and load the next. Thank you all for your ideas!

Comment: Why do you need to load all the images at once?

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `neural-network` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Why do you allocate 10,000 rows but then loop 45,000 times? Anyway, one big problem is that you call `line.split()` 784 times per row when once would suffice. For your actual question, you could save the array as a binary file and read that in.

Comment: Cardinal-ReinstateMonica: Training data  - 
desertnaut: (sorry)  - 
KenY-N I would have never seen that. Thank you so much!

Comment: What machine do you have that is so slow?

Comment: @NomadMaker (2014 chromebook, supplied by the school) :/

Comment: PS: I thought the MNIST data was also supplied in binary format - perhaps you should be reading that instead?

Comment: What type of disk is your training data on? I usually have some SSD's to make my Raspberry Pi's seem fast.

Comment: @KenY-N What do you mean by binary? What does that set look like? Right now I have pretty much a table with 0-255, black-white. Would the binary be easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  array[i][j] = Short.parseShort(line.split(",")[j]);
```

You are calling `String#split()` for every single integer.

Call it once outside the loop and copy the value into your 2d array.

Comment: Thank you so much. I never would have seen that!